# Jmeter test case to capture load balancer server redirect?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a system I want to test that first hits a Tomcat application which is essentially a load balancing redirect.

So the first url that is requested is

```
http://load.balance.server/redirector/
```

That URL redirects the browser to the next available server configured such as:

```
http://target.server.4/targetApp/
```

or

```
http://target.server.5/targetApp/
```

etc...

In my JMeter test case, after the `http://load.balance.server/redirector/` request, I created a 'Regular Expression Extractor' to extract the IP address from the URL.

Then the next entry is going to be:

> http://target.server.[4,5,6]/targetApp/

But when the RegEx extractor runs, it only returns `load.balance.server` from the initial request, not `target.server.[4,5,6]` from the redirected request like I want.

Thus, the subsequent `${HOST}` entries for the http-requests are pointing to `load.balance.server` not to `target.server.[4,5,6]` so the test is failing.

Can someone help me capture the target redirected IP for testing such as testing a load-balanced cluster?

Comment: Have you ticked "Follow Redirects" in your HTTP sampler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put regexp extractor as child of http sampler that has a redirect response

- uncheck follow redirect in sampler
- Check headers in regexp extractir
- Check your regexp , what is it ?

Comment: The issue that I finally solved was the load balancer page was actually returning a JavaScript function that re-posted to a new URL instead of an actual redirect :-O

Comment: So is answer ok ? If yes it should be accepted if not add your own.